# A real circular <div> by css or js means

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there a way to create a real circular div so `overflow:hidden` can hide everything in the div outside the circular region?

I tried using `border-radius, -moz-border-radius, -webkit-border-radius` but `overflow:hidden` only hide things that's outside the square/rectangle region. `border-radius` is indeed only giving an illusion of a circle.

Then I figured I could create a PNG image with a transparent circular area in the middle surrounded by opaque "background-like" region to hide things outside the circular region, but once again it is yet another illusion and it would be useless when the background is not static but changes accordingly to the screen width & height.

So how can I make a **real** circular div? By CSS or JS means?

Comment: `border-radius` constrains background if that helps.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot Tried many time: it doesn't in most browsers.

Comment: not in IE, but there is a way that _I think_ works in both Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: @JanDvorak Sounds good. Mind sharing :) ?

Comment: Really, then a certain widget I wrote a while back wouldn't work in most browsers .... but it does!

Comment: @cartogram oh, sorry. Only webkit, and only prefixed, and not according to the w3c spec derived from the webkit spec

Comment: https://www.webkit.org/blog/181/css-masks/ (and pray it comes to firefox soon)

Comment: Try svg circular image which will change according to screen width & height!

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot really? That's weird.. I tested it in chrome & firefox and it doesn't work..

Comment: Constraining the background is pretty well fundamental to `border-radius`. If it wasn't constrained then any element with both `border-radius` and a `background-color` would be rendered rectangular.

Comment: Also try `-webkit-mask-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, white 0%, white 70%,transparent 70%);`

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot By constrain you mean giving the border pixel(s)? Sorry I didn't get it at the first place. Thanks! You are right without `border:1px solid [color]` the div would appear to be a rectangular though `background-color` fills only the circular region.

Comment: @cartogram, I must confess I've never knowingly tried setting `border-radius` without a `border`.

Comment: Just tried in IE9, Opera and Chrome. All clip background even with no border property set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these links may be it helpful to you http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/
http://border-radius.com/
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp

Comment: Thanks! +1 It is very useful! But the real reason why `overflow:hidden` didn't work the way we expect is because I didn't set the `border:1px solid [color]`

Comment: Thanks @cartogram If you are trying to hide absolute positioned elements make sure the container of those absolute positioned elements is relatively positioned.

Comment: Relative, fixed or absolute itself. Only not static ;)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the comments from you guys.

I just figured it out. Beforehand I've only set `border-radius, -moz-border-radius, -webkit-border-radius` without setting `border:1px solid [color]` thus resulting in the formation of a circular region without `overflow:hidden` working properly. Yet another weird behavior of CSS3.